# The use of "in" & "out of" in the financial context

Tags: prepositions, parallelism

> Amos communications satellites operator Spacecom Satellite
> Communications Ltd. (TASE:SCC) received more than NIS 600 million **in**
> orders in the institutional tender of its bond issue, in which it
> planned to raise NIS 200 million. As a result, the company decided to
> increase the amount of the offering to NIS 309 million in the
> institutional tender.
>
> Spacecom is offering two Consumer Price Index (CPI) linked bond
> series, one at a fixed interest rate, and the other at variable
> interest. **For** the Series 10 bond, the company obtained commitments for
> NIS 250 million at a maximum variable interest rate of 4.5%. **Out of**
> the orders **for** the Series 11 bond, the company obtained commitments
> for NIS 59 million at an interest rate of 3.5%. The company will set
> the final amounts and interest rates for both bonds during the public
> tender next week.
>
> -- Source: [Investor demand triple planned supply for Spacecom bonds](http://www.globes.co.il/en/article-1000553633)

Can I use "**on / from**" instead of "**in**" in the first sentence?

How does "**out of** the orders" match “**for** the Series 11 bond" syntactically? Without "out of the orders" it would make a good comparison:

> **For** the Series 10 bond, the company obtained commitments for
> NIS 250 million at a maximum variable interest rate of 4.5%. **For** the Series 11 bond, the company obtained commitments for NIS 59 million...

Is **out of** redundant here?

I think **out of** here is in the sense of [the following](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/out):

> 6.b. used to say where a person or thing comes from
>
> > I got the idea out of [=from] the book.
> > He had to pay for it out of his own pocket.
> > That meeting was a complete waste of time. I got nothing out of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "*from*" in the first sentence, but it changes the meaning very slightly. "NIS 600 million in orders" means *orders worth 600 million*. On the other hand, *NIS 600 million **from** orders" means "NIS 600 million, earned from orders*. Consider the similar use of "in gold": the sentence "*I have 500 dollars in gold,*" mean you have gold worth 500 dollars.

The object of "*out of*" here is the entire phrase "*orders for the Series 11 bond*". The "for" relates "orders" with "the Series 11 bond".